# Is it safe to store a Dao as a static member on a class?

Tags: java, android, database, concurrency, ormlite

I'm using OrmLite to handle persistence in an Android application.

The OrmLite documentation discusses [DAO Enabled Objects](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#DAO-Enabled-Objects), along with providing a class you can `extend` to tell OrmLite you want to have the `Dao` set on instances of the class that are retrieved from the database.

This has some nice properties, like letting `object.update()` and `object.refresh()` DTRT.

For non-database-generated objects, there is an `object.setDao(Dao)` method you can use.

Would it be problematic to instead just initialise a `Dao` as a static member variable on the class at start?

```
public class Order extends BaseDaoEnabled<Order, Integer> {
    protected static globalDao = null;
    public Order() {
        // Set non-static dao used by parent BaseDaoEnabled
        this.dao = globalDao;
    }
```

In the main class of the program I would initialise `globalDao` once with a Dao appropriate for the object.

This would have the nice property of allowing us to do database operations given an instance of the class even without access to `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao()`.

I **think** this is threadsafe, since my reading of [DaoManager](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/DaoManager.html) indicates there is generally only one Dao per class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[ Sorry for the late response. ]

> Would it be problematic to instead just initialise a Dao as a static member variable on the class at start?

Yes and no.  You need to make sure when the application closes that the DAO is set to `null` so it gets reinitialized when it comes back.  The problem is that I've see applications that are stopped but the classes are still in memory.  Then if the user re-runs the application the `static` initializers will *not* be reinstantiated and old versions of the DAO with now dead connections to the database will be in place.

The right thing to do is to mirror the behavior that the [`DatabaseHelper` class uses in the HelloAndroid project](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-examples/blob/master/android/HelloAndroid/src/com/example/helloandroid/DatabaseHelper.java).  To paraphrase it:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

   private Dao<SimpleData, Integer> simpleDao = null;

   public Dao<SimpleData, Integer> getDao() throws SQLException {
       if (simpleDao == null) {
           simpleDao = getDao(SimpleData.class);
       }
       return simpleDao;
   }

   @Override
   public void close() {
       super.close();
       simpleDao = null;
   }
```